# Should subroutines be identifiable?

Tags: security, subroutine, business-process-management

Should subroutines be identifiable?

I am using a third party BPM product and have a bug with them outstanding concerning subroutine identifiability/tracking.

For example a BPM process has a subroutine coded in java code to enhance the process and I want the ability to know who and what is executing the code for compliance and security reasons.  There is an API to loggedInId to identify who is running the process that doesn't work in this context, my argument is that it should.

This is their response on the bug tracker:

*In the context of an operation(subroutine), the engine will execute the script in an asynchronous and disconnected fashion. Which means that the user currently logged in is not available in that context.*

My question is, is it best practice to allow subroutines to work with complete anonymity as per their response or should the "engine" be aware of who is running the transaction and allow the routine to gather and use it (for recording purposes), hence wanting to use the API?

How do others write secure code that does not run anonymously?

Comment: Not sure if this really fits to Stack Overflow. But IMHO it's bad practice and of course it would be possible to provide any context to any subroutine if you care enough.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear I think in that, in my experience, BPM (or at least BPMN) doesn't use the term "sub-routines".  There are Business Process Diagrams (a.k.a. "Processes"), which have Activities.  Activities can be either "Tasks" or themselves "Processes".  In most BPM systems I have seen Tasks (actual work) are divided into "User" and "System" tasks.  System tasks have no user as they are being done by the BPM System.

Comment: If you so care about context, so respect it! It is unclear what is *subroutine* here. @Drux fairly said that such entity is uncommon in BPMN context so you should specify what BPM-engine you mean.